# laravel difference of session::flash and request->session->flash

Tags: php, performance, session, laravel-5.4, flash-message

i wonder that what is the differences in performance and usage advantage ?

```
public function delete(){
    \Session::flash('success', __('common.message.success.delete'));
}
```

> **vs**

```
public function delete(){
    $request->session()->flash('success', __('common.message.success.delete'))
}
```

please explain it with an open example.
which one is the best performance provide and which one of the right way usage at session ?

Answer (score 2):

They are just different ways of accessing your application's session object. With `laravel` You can access application session

1. Using session facade as `Session::`
2. Using `request's` session method `$request->session()`

You can read on it here [laravel docs for session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session#session-usage). Hope it helps !

Comment: i read it before tons of but i did not find some information about performance.

main goal is performance in here. thanks for your answer